# Product of bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}$ is convergent and all of its terms are positive.  If the sequence ${b_n}$ is bounded, can we conclude that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}{b_n}$ is absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 1):

If $|b_n|\leq B$ for all $n$, then 
$$|a_nb_n|=a_n|b_n|\leq Ba_n$$
for all $n$ since $a_n>0$. So what can you say about $\sum_n|a_nb_n|$?

Answer (score 0):

If the first is convergent and all $a_n$ are positive then it is abs convergent. This property is preserved when multiplying by uniformly bounded numbers.